# Calling C Function Passing 2 Struct Pointers As Arguments

Tags: c, pointers, struct, types

I'm having issues trying to call a function where I pass in pointers to two structs.

Please could someone explain why I can't do this...

```
// in types.h

typedef struct {

    uint16_t size;
    uint16_t width;
    uint16_t height;
    void (*fn_init)(void);

} display_t, *display_ptr;

typedef struct {

    uint16_t size;
    const display_ptr display;

} context_t, *context_ptr;

// in main.c

void init_context(context_ptr context, const display_ptr display) {
    context->size = sizeof(context_t);
    context->display = display;
}

const display_t g_display= {
    0,
    400,
    800,
    NULL
};

context_t g_context;

void main(void) {

    // other code here...

    init_context(&g_context, &g_display);

}
```

When I call the init_context function, I get the following error:

`"argument of type "display_t const *" is incompatible with parameter of type struct <unnamed> *"`

However, if I alter the declaration of the init_context to be as follows:

```
void init_context(context_ptr context, const display_t *display);
```

It works!

What am I missing or not understanding?

Thanks in advance!
Kev

Comment: You're trying to modify `context->display` but it's defined as `const`.

Comment: There is a difference between `const Foo*` and `Foo * const`. One is a regular pointer to a constant Foo, the other is a constant pointer to a regular Foo. Your problem is that typedef'd pointer types work counterintuitively with const. It's best not to typedef pointer types.

Comment: Alejandro - Thanks but that isn't the cause of error.

Comment: Fixed. Removed the pointer declaration from the typedef struct and added "typedef const display_t* display_ptr;" which now works. Thanks @n.m.

Comment: [Is it a good idea to `typedef` pointers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers)

Comment: Once solved, please post the answere and mark as solved.